# Extend background video and navigation bar across all pages in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to have my background video and navigation bar spread across all pages I make but I also want them to be behind all of the other components rendered. I understand that I need to wrap the root element inside of gatsby-browser.js but the problem I have been faced with is that the background covers all of the elements. Is there any way to fix this?

Current gatsby-browser.js - Currently covers all components with background.

```
import React from 'react';
import BackGround from "../../src/components/bg"

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <BackGround>{element}</BackGround>;
};

"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _interopRequireWildcard2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard"));

/* global __PATH_PREFIX__ */
// Taken from https://github.com/netlify/netlify-identity-widget
var routes = /(confirmation|invite|recovery|email_change)_token=([^&]+)/;
var errorRoute = /error=access_denied&error_description=403/;
var accessTokenRoute = /access_token=/;

export const onInitialClientRender = function (_, _ref) {
  var _ref$enableIdentityWi = _ref.enableIdentityWidget,
      enableIdentityWidget = _ref$enableIdentityWi === void 0 ? true : _ref$enableIdentityWi,
      _ref$publicPath = _ref.publicPath,
      publicPath = _ref$publicPath === void 0 ? "admin" : _ref$publicPath;
  var hash = (document.location.hash || "").replace(/^#\/?/, "");

  if (enableIdentityWidget && (routes.test(hash) || errorRoute.test(hash) || accessTokenRoute.test(hash))) {
    Promise.resolve().then(function () {
      return (0, _interopRequireWildcard2.default)(require("netlify-identity-widget"));
    }).then(function (_ref2) {
      var netlifyIdentityWidget = _ref2.default;
      netlifyIdentityWidget.on("init", function (user) {
        if (!user) {
          netlifyIdentityWidget.on("login", function () {
            document.location.href = __PATH_PREFIX__ + "/" + publicPath + "/";
          });
        }
      });
      netlifyIdentityWidget.init();
    });
  }
};
```

If any additional information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Can you add a working sandbox? It's difficult to debug that code without one.

Comment: Don't worry about anything below line 6 that's for netlify cms

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [`wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement) nor [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement) APIs fits your requirements since they will wrap your entire page in a provided component, and that's what you are trying to avoid. Of course, they will prevent your component to be unmounted, however, this will be automatically handled by `@reach/routing` with the following approach.

What you are trying to achieve it's a simple shared component across all pages that extends from your `<Layout>`:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return <section>
    <BackGround>
       <YourNavigationComponent />
    </BackGround>
    <main>{children}</main>
  </section>;
};
```

Something like this will wrap your `<YourNavigationComponent />` with your background component across all site, avoiding the wrapping of the whole elements.